# lwc - problem on calling of inner js function

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on a dynamic lwc lightning data table, everything working with apex data. I am facing a problem to call the inner JS function.

Like in below code `next()` is a function which is the part of the pagination, I would like to get the next data set based on incremental of OFFSET,

**Problem** is next() function is getting call `buildSOQL()`(create soql on other params) function but it is not calling other inner js function. Please suggest why `buildSOQL()` is not working on a call of `next()` function.

```js
    import { LightningElement, wire, track, api } from "lwc";
    import getRecords from "@salesforce/apex/RelatedList.getRecords";
    import countRecords from "@salesforce/apex/RelatedList.countRecords";

    export default class LightningDatatable extends LightningElement {
      // Public Property
      @api objectName;
      @api columns;
      @api relatedFieldAPI;
      @api whereClause;
      @api limit = 10;
      // Private Property
      @track data = [];
      @track soql;
      @track offSet = 0;
      @track totalRows = 0;
      @track isDisablePrev = this.offSet == 0 ? true : false;
      @track isDisableNext = this.offSet > this.totalRows ? true : false;
      // Do init funtion
      connectedCallback() {
        this.buildSOQL();
        console.log("soql::", this.soql);
        //Count number of rows
        countRecords({ objectName: this.objectName }).then(result => {
          console.log("data", result);
        });
      }

      //@wire property to call apex
      @wire(getRecords, { soql: "$soql" }) accounts({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
          this.data = data;
        } else if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
      //Next button to get the next data
      next(event) {
        this.offSet = this.offSet + this.limit;
        this.buildSOQL();
      }

      //Previous button to get the previous data
      previous(event) {}

      /*********************************************************************
       * All Helper Method's
       *********************************************************************/

      //Generic function to build soql
      buildSOQL() {
        let soql = this.appendField();
        if (this.whereClause) soql += this.appendWhere();
        soql += this.appendLimit();
        soql += this.appendOffset();
        this.soql = soql;
      }

      appendField() {
        let cols = JSON.parse(this.columns),
          soql = "SELECT Id,",
          col = [];
        if (cols) {
          this.columns = cols;
          cols.map(val => {
            col.push(val["fieldName"]);
          });
          soql = soql + `${col.join(",")} FROM ${this.objectName}`;
        }
        return soql;
      }

      appendWhere() {
        return ` WHERE ${this.whereClause}`;
      }

      appendLimit() {
        return ` LIMIT ${this.limit}`;
      }

      appendOffset() {
        return ` OFFSET ${this.offSet}`;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think limit is immutable (it's a number and annotated with `@api`... to get a fresh copy, try stringObj.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(limit,10))

Comment: Actually, because it's a primative, you might be able to just got `let mutableLimit = limit;`

Comment: API parameters cannot be updated by the component itself (not that I can see where this is done, so accessing this.limit should be fine). Note that API properties are passed in and, IIRC, you get a proxy object. It may be that you want to get a mutable version you want to do something like `let mutableLimit = this.limit + 0;`

Comment: The main area of concern to me is how the isDisabledPrev and isDisabledNext are calculated - this won't work. Move this logic into where offset and totalRows are managed.